# How to prevent duplicate selections from array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am making a program in Jgrasp that stores words from a text file in arrays. There are 2 files and 2 arrays, one stores words spelled correctly and the other words spelled incorrectly. The program then randomly selects a word from one of the 2 arrays and asks the user if it is spelled correctly. I've got everything running great, but need a way to prevent words from being selected more than once. Code is posted below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class wordGame
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      boolean more = true;
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(more)
      {
         run(); 
         System.out.println("Another player?");
         String answer = kb.next();
         if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            more = false;
      }
      System.out.println("Good Bye");
   }
   public static void run() throws Exception
   {
      String[] correct = new String[10];
      String[] incorrect = new String[10];
      //static void description()
      description();
      //static void fillArray(String[] correct, String[] incorrect)
      fillArray(correct, incorrect);
      //static void play(String[] correct, String[] incorrect)
      play(correct, incorrect);
   }
   //actual play
   public static void play(String[] correct, String[] incorrect)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random();
      int points = 0;
      for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      {
         
         //genreate a random number either 0 or 1
         int r = rand.nextInt(2);
         if(r == 0)
         {
            //generate a random number between 0-9 inclusive (rand.nextInt(10))
            int index = rand.nextInt(10);
            //display the word on the string from the correct array at the given index
            System.out.println("Is the word ***"+correct[index]+"*** spelled correctly?");
            //ask the the user to enter if the word is spelled correctly or not y/n
            System.out.print("y/n: ");
            String answer = kb.next();
            //if the users answer is yes increment points by 1, otherwise decrement by 1
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
               points++;
            else
               points--;   
         }
         else
         {
               int index = rand.nextInt(10);
            //display the word on the string from the correct array at the given index
            System.out.println("Is the word ***"+incorrect[index]+"*** spelled correctly?");
            //ask the the user to enter if the word is spelled correctly or not y/n
            System.out.print("y/n: ");
            String answer = kb.next();
            //if the users answer is yes increment points by 1, otherwise decrement by 1
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
               points++;
            else
               points--; 
         }   
      }
      System.out.println("Your score: "+points);
   }
   public static void fillArray(String[] correct, String[] incorrect) throws Exception
   {
      //create a file object
      File f1 = new File("correct.txt");
      //create a pointer to the file
      Scanner input1 = new Scanner(f1);//input: name of scanner pulling info from file
      int index1 = 0;
      //fill in the array correct
      while(input1.hasNextLine() && index1 < correct.length)
      {
         //read one word
         String word = input1.nextLine();
         //store it in the array
         correct[index1] = word;
         index1++;
      }
      //create a file object
      File f2 = new File("incorrect.txt");
      //create a pointer to the file
      Scanner input2 = new Scanner(f2);//input: name of scanner pulling info from file
      int index2 = 0;
      //fill in the array incorrect
      while(input2.hasNextLine() && index2 < incorrect.length)
      {
         //read one word
         String word = input2.nextLine();
         //store it in the array
         incorrect[index2] = word;
         index2++;
      }      
   } 
   // displays instructions for the game
   public static void description()
   {
      System.out.printf("%40s", "Welcome to Misspelled!!");
      System.out.printf("\n%41s", "Please play resonbsibly!!");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.printf("\n%39s", "THE RULES OF THE GAME\n");
      System.out.println("You will be shown a series of 10 words that are spelled correctly or incorrectly");
      System.out.println("Answer y if it is spelled correctly, n if it is spelled incorrectly");
      System.out.println("Correct answers will award you 1 point, incorrect answers will lose you 1 point");
      System.out.println("");
      
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you use a List rather than an array, then removing the element would be easier.  Another idea would be to shuffle your data and then iterate sequentially.

Comment: list would be easier, but part of the assignment is that I have to use an array and we can't use shuffle as the words have to be truly randomly selected.

Comment: In that case maybe just keep a array of previously chosen indices, then each time check that this new index has not been used before.  BUT *we can't use shuffle as the words have to be truly randomly selected.*  it makes not difference if you shuffle the data or shuffle the indices, you are still getting the same random selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  I use `ints` for demonstration purposes but the method is easily adapted to any data type.  It is similar to what [@ScaryWombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) suggested.  It does a shuffle on the fly but random selection is still used.

- it simply selects a random value `t`.
- moves the value indexed by `size-1`  into `t's` slot
- updates `size` and returns `t`
- if no more values, it returns -1

```
int[] vals = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int size = vals.length;
Random r = new Random();
    
int i;
while ((i = getValue()) > 0) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");  
}
```

prints something like

```
3 1 8 9 10 2 6 7 4 5
```

The method

Note that this method does not preserve the contents of the list. If you want to do so, uncomment the commented out statement.  But the list will still end up randomized.

```
public static int getValue() {
    if (size > 0) {
        int idx = r.nextInt(size);
        int t = vals[idx];
        vals[idx] = vals[--size];
        // vals[size] = t;
        return t;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That seems like a ton of pointless effort. All you need is `Collections.shuffle`, if it's fair game to destroy the underlying collection type. The one advantage this strategy has is that if you're grabbing 10 random items without replacement from an array of a few million, this is useful. It doesn't look like OP is doing that, though.

Comment: Why is this pointless effort? The OP wants to `"prevent duplicate selections"`.  That's  not the same as handling them if they happen.   The OP said they can't use Lists. And even if they could, they can't use `Collections.shuffle` So they probably can't use Sets or any other API based data structure.  So this solution meets the requirements.

Comment: Instead of the algorithm of 'pick random item between 0 and X, then swap that with X, then X--', you can instead go with 'shuffle collection, then iterate through it as normal'. Given that 'shuffle the collection' is a known thing with built-in methods to do it, the latter is significantly less code and significantly less error-prone. However, OPs choice to go with an array complicates matters a tad. I just checked, `Arrays.shuffle(int[])` does not appear to exist for some utterly bizarre reason.

Comment: My example was using `ints`  for a simple demonstration.  But since the OP wants to use Strings the OP could use `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(stringArray))`.  This will shuffle the array since it backs the List. But lists are still involved internally as a transition element so I'm not certain that would be permitted.  Note that this won't work for primitive arrays.